# Navigating within directories with name having spaces

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am using Windows 7, EmacsW32 and Emacs23

I am trying to navigate inside a directory whose name has spaces with within Emacs. So, I try to navigate to it in Dired mode by:

C-x d

And then navigate to the directory name with spaces (e.g. My Documents) and the suggestion and auto-complete feature (upon pressing TAB) does not work. How can I navigate to folders and files within such directories without removing spaces?

UPDATE: I tried few other paths with spaces in some directories, and it works. i don't know in which situations it works and fails. It works for Program Files but fails for My Documents.

Comment: I don't understand your problem clearly. you mean auto complete "My Documents" in mini-buffer after C-x d?

Comment: Well, when you C-x d, you can TAB which gives you a list of the files and folders under the current directory you are in. This list appears in a seperate window, not the mini-buffer. When you navigate to My Documents, and then press TAB, no such list appears even though you could have files in that directory. This happens whenever your current directory name has a space.

Comment: Which os? I have no problems with spaces and autocomplete on the patched windows version (emacs23). Is it actually spaces or are it stuck on selecting between ´My Documents´ and ´My Photos´ or whatever

Comment: Windows 7. Emacs23. Downloaded from: http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html

Comment: Isn't "My Documents" some kind of symlink-like thing in Windows Vista & 7? That's probably the cause. Try `C:\Users\(username)\Documents` (or something like that).

Comment: With doesn't work do you mean that it doesn't give you any autocompletion at all or does it autocomplete up until the space in the folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with folders with spaces in it. The problem is only with My Documents, My Videos and similarly named folders.

When I go in the windows file browser and check the path of the folder My Documents, it appears as C:/..../Documents/...

So, I tried to open Documents instead of My Documents in Emacs and it works. Now I am able to access my files under Documents.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a shot in the dark, but unix's case escapes are "\ " and I believe windows does the same.

Comment: No I tried that. I edited the mini-buffer and typed My\ Documents. Doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry:( Like I said, shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem directly.

As you described, I think you may not use [ido-mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) now. The default tab complete in emacs is weak. Try ido-mode, it is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this particular issue, however:

To enter a literal space, type <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>

`C-q` runs the command `quoted-insert` which ensures that the next character typed is inserted into the current buffer, which can be useful when the key in question is bound to some function.